# Extract data from Relations 

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm making an online shop. I have two models: `Product` and `Category`. `Product` can have one category, while category can have many products.

I've defined relationships in `models`. I can access categories and products. But I want to get all products from specific category. I've tried many examples of relational queries with "lazy" and "eager" approach from official documentation, but no success. Can you please explain how to implement it?

Here's my code:

Category controller:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'products' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Product', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

Product controller:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: placed your figured out approach with some changes and you can mark it as answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Category::model()->with('products')->findByPk(1);
```

you can access fields like

```
$the_category->products->name
```

This returns array and you can see content for `debugging purposes` by

```
CVarDumper::Dump($the_category->products->name,100,true);
```

of you can use `foreach` loop to access each `index`

```
$products = $the_category->products;
foreach ($products as $the_product) 
{
    echo "Name: " . $the_product['name'] . "<br />";
}
```