# Dataprovider and relations (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I was struggling with one [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330040/extract-data-from-relations) today, but managed to solve it by myself.
Now I have another problem. I've found that it is better to use CActiveDataProvider class for such situations. Here's the code of my DataProvider:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Category', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'with'=>array('products'),
                'condition'=>'t.id=1',
            ),
));
```

Then I've passed this data provider to a widget, but couldn't access its values.
If someone can, please guide me through the process. Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? And what is the result?

Comment: I want to accomplish the same as result as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330040/extract-data-from-relations)  example, but through the List widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working with the help of Yii community (thank you :))
Here's the code for controller:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Product', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>array('category'),
                'condition'=>'category.id=:id',
                'params'=>array(':id'=>$id),
    ),
));
```

Comment: i've set the pagination. but when i click on next it shows no record found. but i have the records. plz help me....

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what your widget requires. 
`CActiveDataProvider` is a wrapper for `CActiveRecord` with extended capabilities of **sorting, pagination and filtering.** Typically `CActiveDataProvider` is being used in conjunction with zii widgets like `CListView` or `CGridView` which are utilizing its sort and search capabilities.

So if you want to display data in terms of list or table with (optional) sorting/filtering/pagination - most convenient way of doing it in Yii is using described zii widgets or their extensions.

If you just need to fetch data and use it in any other way, but without smart rendering mechanisms provided by `CListView` or `CGridView` - use `CActiveRecord`, because it doesn't perform anything else except of fetching of data.

> I've found that it is better to use CActiveDataProvider class for such
>   situations

you can equally use `CActiveRecord` to do the magic of relations

Comment: Yes, i need pagination and filtering. Can you guide me through the process?

Comment: what input type your widget requires

Comment: It must simply retrieve information from the database. No input needed.
Sorry, if it's not clear.

Comment: ok do `CVarDumper::Dump($CActiveDataProvider,100,true)` to see does actually your active provider has something or is it null

Comment: Yes, it has data that i need.